# Does Crystal Reports have an equivalent of a master page?

Tags: crystal-reports

Let's say I have a logo that I want to appear in the same place on a set of reports (many files). Is there a way for me to put that logo into the equivalent of a master page and apply that master page to all the pages of my reports? I'd like the logo to appear in the same place on a variety of documents without having to mess around with copypasta.

Using CR 9.2 (ouch, call the archeology dept eh?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to **add a new header or footer section that includes your logo**.

In Crystal 2008 (sorry, it's all I have) this is done by right clicking on any of the header/footer sections (e.g. Report header, page header, group footer, etc.) and then selecting "**Insert Section Below**".

This gets you a new section that will repeat at the top or bottom of every new section/page.  Any logos pasted into a page header will be reused for each page.

Note that you can have as many "page header" sections as you want if you find it helpful to split up the header into multiple vertically stacked sections.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago they used to have an page header and page footer. Not sure about the current version of Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a report as [MasterReport] with the logo in any where of it then you should insert a subreport into it. MasterReport equivalent of the master page and the subreport is like the placeHolders in asp.net and you can create this subreport like a dynamic report.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a subreport to a report, crystal reporter creates a copy of subreport and save it into main report so you can not change the subreport by code at run time.